# Usar tipo declarado posteriormente en una estructura

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Tengo estas estructuras

```
typedef struct stDC {
    qint8 numberA;
    qint16 numberB;
    qint32 numberC;
    qint64 numberD;
    qint32 *intList;
    qint8 *byteList;
    stDC *list;
    int listlen;
    QString string;
    int mode;
    float floatv;
    double doublev;
} DataComplex;

typedef struct stTab {
    QString name;
    DataComplex value;
} Tab;

typedef struct stTree {
    QString name;
    Tab data[255];
    int data_n;
    stTree *branches[255];
    int branches_num;
} Tree;
```

Pero necesito agregar un array de punteros Tree a DataComplex es esto posible?, y si lo es como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es perfectamente posible; y, además, muy simple: **pre-declarando**:

```
struct stTree; // <- PRE-DECLARAMOS.

typedef struct stDC {
  qint8 numberA;
  qint16 numberB;
  qint32 numberC;
  qint64 numberD;
  qint32 *intList;
  qint8 *byteList;
  stDC *list;
  int listlen;
  QString string;
  int mode;
  float floatv;
  double doublev;
  stTree *que_facil_es[1024]; // <-- AQUÍ.
} DataComplex;
```

En la pre-declaración, informamos al compilador de que un identificador es una clase; así, cuando el compilador encuentre dicho identificador, sabe que **lo vamos a declarar** mas pronto o mas tarde, y no se queja.

Si te fijas detalladamente, verás que **ya lo estas haciendo**, incluso antes de formular la pregunta:

```
typedef struct stTree {
  QString name;
  Tab data[255];
  int data_n;
  stTree *branches[255]; // <-- ¿¿ Cómo es posible esto ??
};
```

¿ Como es posible que uses un *arreglo* de punteros a `stTree` **antes** de terminar de declarar la `struct` ?

Esta técnica solo es válida **si vamos a usar punteros o referencias**; por ejemplo:

```
struct stTree; // <- PRE-DECLARAMOS.

typedef struct stDC {
  qint8 numberA;
  ...
  stTree que_facil_es; // <-- ESTO ES UN ERROR.
} DataComplex;
```

Piensa que el compilador **necesita** conocer el tamaño de los tipos; en el código anterior, **no lo sabe**; por lo tanto, no sabe cuanta memoria ha de usar, y *se queja*.

Sin embargo, **siempre sabe el tamaño de un puntero**, que es lo que tú realmente quieres usar; por ello, con decirle que `stTree` es un tipo válido, no necesita mas.

Una última cosa: en C++, **no es necesario** hacer `typedef` para las clases (ni para las `struct`, que son un tipo de clase):

```
struct Tree;

struct DataComplex {
  qint8 numberA;
  qint16 numberB;
  qint32 numberC;
  qint64 numberD;
  qint32 *intList;
  qint8 *byteList;
  DataComple *list;
  int listlen;
  QString string;
  int mode;
  float floatv;
  double doublev;
  Tree *que_chulo[1024];
};

struct Tab {
  QString name;
  DataComplex value;
};

struct Tree {
  QString name;
  Tab data[255];
  int data_n;
  Tree *branches[255];
  int branches_num;
};
```